# Should I specify "Vary: If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since"?

Tags: http, caching, vary

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4):

> The "Vary" header field in a response describes what parts of a
> request message, aside from the method, Host header field, and
> request target, might influence the origin server's process for
> selecting and representing this response.

Comment: Vary's main purpose is to ensure clients get the right representation of a resource, when Content Negotiation is in play. Caching isn't Content Negotiation.

Comment: Although, the RFC clearly states that informing caches is one of the purposes of the `Vary` header field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The [RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4):

> An origin server SHOULD send a Vary header field when its algorithm
> for selecting a representation varies based on aspects of the request
> message other than the method and request target

In this case, the representation is not determined by the value of those headers. They are used to decide whether or not a body should be sent.

As a hint:

> For example, there is no
> need to send the Authorization field name in Vary because reuse
> across users is constrained by the field definition

Likewise for for conditional request fields.